# How to recover my Eclipse Workspace - Everything is gone?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I opened Eclipse this morning and the workspace would not open. I started looking around, and all the files in my `../android/workspace/` directory are gone. There is nothing in the recycle bin.

Can this be recovered? What is going on?

Comment: Sure, just go to your backups and restore the files. What, you didn't _have_ a backup? Then let this be a valuable life lesson and be thankful you didn't make this mistake the first time where _important_ data was involved, like your wedding photos :-)

Comment: Have you tried searching for any of the files? (Aside from where you thought they were, and the trash can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how this is handled on a mac but i am using windows and there are plenty of tools that can recover deleted files from the hard drive. Sure this is an important lesson and should make you start using version control tools and making backups but regardless whats done its done. just search for something like that on the web. a file is not removed from the hard drive untill it is overwritten and even then there are people and software that can recover those files.

if you haven't heard data gets recovered from broken, opened hard drives and recovering from a functional drive is a piece of cake in comparison.

You will just spend a lot of your time sorting out the recovered data...

[More Info!](http://tinyurl.com/yd6rpoh)

hope this helps, 
Have fun.